# VBA Excel perform operations on filtered data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset with headers 'Item ID', 'Item Number', 'Item Description', 'Authorized' and 'Included'.

I need to write a piece of VBA code that will filter the data, store the row indices of the filtered rows, count how many items made it through the filter, and store the filtered data into a temporary array/variable/matrix (whatever it is in VBA) in the locals window.

For example, if I filter these 40 rows by Item Description is equal to F..

```
Item ID Item Number Item Description Authorized Included
91099   96  O   416 359
1147    21  K   576 393
86077   26  J   50  883
3738    21  F   131 671
88084   74  T   921 535
68014   100 H   303 680
70440   19  B   435 293
25844   65  V   64  285
77342   79  Y   315 346
61486   23  X   380 488
37582   30  S   585 807
27215   81  D   635 877
58618   58  E   531 200
30313   95  T   154 870
2240    76  F   363 818
63700   100 G   514 67
7046    60  R   752 907
67399   21  D   86  89
62552   23  V   616 68
77686   12  B   628 889
50082   69  J   539 429
434 73  U   942 258
62964   49  Y   422 849
11982   16  H   367 97
751 95  K   250 373
50195   31  I   663 376
81141   9   M   291 359
30809   48  N   556 190
84080   20  H   897 960
84039   77  J   899 77
62669   49  K   966 221
1664    43  L   800 353
70525   29  O   475 657
93961   3   W   423 413
7562    98  S   440 952
48109   66  X   122 69
45892   26  C   681 121
33574   90  D   476 58
62539   24  Q   761 795
64962   21  R   623 375
```

I get 2 that rows that make it through the filter

```
Item ID Item Number Item Description Authorized Included
3738    21  F   131 671
2240    76  F   363 818
```

I want 2 rows stored in a local but also an array with the respective row indices (5 and 16).

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data? The Excel 2007+ AutoFilter would allow you to manipulate this nicely without the need for code. Again, this depends on what you need to do with the data. For more information: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-HA010370616.aspx

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, and what error are you getting in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? My code is definitely not optimized, but it illustrates how to use ListObject to filter cells and save the results in an array:

```
Sub FilterRange()

    Dim lo As ListObject

    'create list object (table)
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=Range("A1:E41"), XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
    lo.Name = "myTable"

    'apply filter (could not get field parameter to work with named column)
    lo.Range.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="F", Operator:=xlAnd

    'assign range to array
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim iCols, iRows As Integer
    iCols = Range("A1:E41").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns.Count
    iRows = Range("A1:E41").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count

    'dim array - add an extra column for row id
    ReDim aResults(iRows, iCols + 1)

    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim c As Variant

    'Iterate through filtered areas copying values into array - change to
    '      Range("A1:E41").Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
    '      to skip the header row.
    i = 0
    For Each area In Range("A1:E41").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        j = 1
        For Each c In area
            aResults(i, 0) = c.Row      'row number
            aResults(i, j) = c.Value
            j = j + 1
        Next c
        i = i + 1
    Next area

   'print
   ' For i = 0 To UBound(aResults, 1) - 1
   '     For j = 0 To UBound(aResults, 2) - 1
   '         Debug.Print aResults(i, j)
   '     Next j
   ' Next i
End Sub
```

Clear the filter with something like:

```
Sub UnfilterRange()
    'turn table back to range

    'if no tables, then ignore and continue
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ListObjects("myTable").Unlist

End Sub
```